# How to open Spring perspective in Spring Tool Suite 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

In STS 3 the default perspective is Spring, but in STS 4 the Spring option is not in the perspective list. Is there any way to change it to Spring in STS 4?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Tools 4 don't contain any Spring perspective anymore, the major elements got added to the regular Java perspective, since that is what most people use for daily Spring Boot app development. So if you open an existing workspace that had the Spring perspective open from STS3 with STS4, you should close that perspective and continue with the Java one instead.

Ref: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-spring-boot-aka-spring-tool-suite-4

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same, i solved mine by changing the Java version in my eclipse.ini file :

So in eclipse.ini :

Look for(
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
)

Change to(
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
)
And that worked.

Comment: do not forget to restart eclipse.

Comment: FI : Resetting perspective http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9j.htm